# Appcelerator on Windows 10, module build issues

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

I have installed **Appcelerator Studio** on **Windows 10**. Arrow projects built and deployed to Android device successfully.
I have Native module created from **Appcelerator Studio** template according to official guide: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Module_Quick_Start

And while publishing(to any target - Titanium SDK, Mobile App and location) next error appears:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.2.2.GA\module\android\build.xml:165: no executable specified
```

All SKD's and tools installed according to guide.

Comment: This error originates from [this line](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/support/module/android/build.xml#L156-L165) so it seems like it can't find the `aidl` executable. Check what Android SDK build tools version you are using

Comment: @FokkeZandbergen: See my answer below. It's kind of odd, but it works just adding .exe to the code.